# C++ error Type 'std::thread' could not be resolved Eclipse Mars 4.5 , Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading

I am quite desperate. Eclipse keeps on giving the error

```
'std::thread' could not be resolved
```

I of course `#include <thread>`

I tried also the following which I found in another question in stackoverflow:
Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT GCC Build-in Compiler Settings
in the text box entitled Command to get compiler specs append -std=c++11

NOW it looks like: `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD  -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"`

Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect

select ISO C++11 from the Language standard drop down.

But it does not work. Anyone can help?

UPDATE: I updated the compiler to version 4.8. The error is still there, but it compiles, and it even works... so it is enough for me! Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: you meant "I of course #include <thread>"?

Comment: The standard C++ compiler in Ubuntu 12.04 is most likely to old know the option `-std=c++11`, you can try `-std=c++0x`. If that doesn't help either, then you need to upgrade to a newer compiler with better C++11 support.

Comment: I mean with that that I included  #include <thread>

Comment: As stated by Joachim can you post the gcc version? That would help a lot. And possibly all the compiler output.

Comment: gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: Compiler output in eclipse: in the console, it seems everything ok. But in the field "problems" the sentence is "Type 'std::thread' could not be resolved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `std=c++11` flag was only added in `gcc` 4.7. Try upgrading you compiler or else try the option supported in `gcc` 4.6, namely: `std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with eclipse oxygen. Removing support for `pthread` in the linker and compiler solved it for me.