# CLion cannot resolve thread

Tags: c++11, clion

I'm writing a Multithreading program based on C++ 11 using "JetBrains CLion 2017.1". The code is here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void thread_task() {
    std::cout << "hello thread" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t(thread_task);
    t.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the "CMakeLists.txt" is default:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(AgileDev)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(AgileDev ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But CLion cannot resolve "thread":
Error picture
[image]

I wondered where I was wrong. (T^T)

Comment: This link is for eclipse, but you cold be facing a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184177/c-error-type-stdthread-could-not-be-resolved-eclipse-mars-4-5-ubuntu-12

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error. Apparently if you are using mingw it doesn't support standard threads. You should download this: https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

and add `mingw.mutex.h` and `mingw.thread.h` to your project directory.Include  this at the top of your cpp source file.

```
#include "mingw.thread.h"
```

It should work then